# How to style the first row of every tr group?

Tags: html, css, datatables, grouping

I want to place a button to expand child rows on my datatable, where each group in the datatable should have the same child....

The following css places the icon on every row in the entire table

```
    td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

How can I style only the first (or middle if possible) row in each group to have the icon for the child rows?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: Datatables initialization, to give a demo of the basic structure..**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

    $('#myDataTable thead tr#filterrow th').each(function () {

        var title = $('#myDataTable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" onclick="stopPropagation(event);" placeholder="Search ' + title + '""style="direction: ltr; text-align:left;" />');

    });
    $("#myDataTable thead input").on('keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });

    var table = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
        //"scrollY": "200",
        "scroller": "true",
        "deferRender": "true",
        "orderCellsTop": "true",
        "columnDefs":
            [
                { "visible": false, "targets": 1 },
                {
                    "className": 'details-control', "targets": 0
                },
                 {
                     "orderable": false, "targets": 0
                 }
            ],

        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "displayLength": 100,
        "drawCallback": function (settings)
        {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            var last = null;
            api.column(1, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                if (last !== group) {
                    $(rows).eq(i).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="91">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );

                    last = group;
                }

            });
        }
    });
    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
            that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });

    // Order by the grouping
    $('#myDataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function () {
        var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
        if (currentOrder[0] === 1 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
            table.order([1, 'desc']).draw();
        }
        else {
            table.order([1, 'asc']).draw();
        }
    });

    $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable(
        {
            "aoColumns":
            [.........]
        });
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#myDataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        console.log(table.row(this).data());
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown())
        {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: include your HTML code too..

Comment: I can't share it, its kinda private...

However, its a fairly simple dataTable with a group, and rows under it, formatted through jQuery Datatables

Comment: We don't need the full content...just a demo of the **basic** table structure. Are you using multiple `tbody` elements?

Comment: no, just one tbody..

Comment: have you tried using `td.details-control:first-child` everywhere you want the first one to be styled??

Comment: :) sorry I missed `-child`

Comment: ah, a dude already posted this as an answer, it doesn't work, i tried this at first on my own...still gives me an icon on every row in every group..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tr.group + tr td.details-control {
    background: url('../Content/DataTables/images/details_open.png') no-repeat left center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.group + tr.shown td.details-control{
    background: url('../Content/DataTables/images/details_close.png') no-repeat left center;
}
```

Does the trick....I adjusted Andrea Ghidini's answer

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your HTML I have to guess that it's something like:

```
<table>
  <tr class="group">[...]</tr>
  <tr class="shown">[...]</tr>
  <tr class="shown">[...]</tr>
  <tr class="shown">[...]</tr>
  <tr class="group">[...]</tr>
  <tr class="shown">[...]</tr>
</table>
```

If that's the case you can use the adjacent sibling selector `tr.group + tr.shown` to select the first `.shown` sibling after each `.group`.

Comment: What about when it is not shown?  Note my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Use the pseudo class `first-child`

```
.table-class tr:first-child{
    // css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can write like below ways:

```
table.test-table tr:first-child{
   /* enter css code here */
}
```